# searching a perl hash for a value

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm reading in an xml file using XMLin and it gives me this...

```
'Date' => '01Jan2013',
'Total' => 3,
'Details' => {
    'Detail' => [
                 {
                 'Name' => 'Bill',
                 'ID' => '123',
                 'IP' => '255.255.255.1'
                 },
                 {
                 'Name' => 'Ted',
                 'ID' => '456',
                 'IP' => '255.255.255.2'
                 },
                 {
                 'Name' => 'Fred',
                 'ID' => '789',
                 'IP' => '255.255.255.3'
                 },
             ]
      }
```

I'm trying to search the {Detail}[Name] values for a particular name. So I want to search for Fred to get his name and IP address.

```
foreach my $ruleline ($pricesettings->{Details}{Detail}['Name']){
    if ($pricesettings->{Details}{Detail}["Name"] eq "Fred") {
        print "Found you\n"; 
    }
    else {
        print "Not found\n";
    }
}
```

But even if I print Dumper($pricesettings->{Details}{Detail}['Name']) within the for loop it only prints the first record entries for Bill.

Ideally I want to see output like

```
Name => 'Bill'<br>
Name => 'Ted'<br>
Name => 'Fred'<br>
```

Then if Fred is found I want to get Fred's IP address or ID. I have no problem finding or comparing the value 'Date' or 'Total' for example, but each grouping under 'Detail' is causing me a problem.

Comment: That's because arrays are indexed by number and `'Name'` is being treated as zero.

Comment: It looks like you are saying that you are using `XML::Simple->XMLin()`, in which case it might be a good idea to upgrade to a better XML module, such as [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3A%3ALibXML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code snippet is slightly off. instead, try

```
foreach my $ruleline (@{$pricesettings->{Details}{Detail}}){
    if ( $ruleline->{"Name"} eq "Fred") {
        print "Found you\n"; 
    }
    else {
        print "Not found\n";
    }
}
```

In order to arrive at the output you actually aim at, try the following:

```
foreach my $ruleline (@{$pricesettings->{Details}{Detail}}){
    print "Name -> '$$ruleline{Name}'" ; 
    if ( $$ruleline{Name} eq "Fred") {
        print "; ID -> '$$ruleline{ID}', IP -> '$$ruleline{IP}';" ; 
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

technical explanation:
in your original code you've mixed up arrays and hashes. for complex data structures of the kind you employ consider switching to an oo programming style, maybe using [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1005/lib/Moose.pm) (though that might be overkill).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much for this. Its spot on.